# can't get data from ng-model using signalr

Tags: angularjs, signalr

here is my .html :

```
 <ul class="messages list-unstyled" ng-repeat="newMessage in messages">
                    <li>
                        <p>
                            <span class="username">{{newMessage.username}}</span><br />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <span> {{newMessage.message}}</span>
                        </p>

                        <p class="no-pad-bottom date-posted">Send {{ newMessage.date }} <span /></p>

                        <div class="comments">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="newComment in comments">
                                <li>
                                    <p>
                                        <span class="commentor"> {{newComment.username}}</span>
                                        <span> {{newComment.message}}</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="no-pad-bottom date-posted">Send {{ newComment.date }} <span /></p>
                                </li>

                            </ul>

                            <form class="add-comment">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myComment" placeholder="Add a comment" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" ng-click="addComment(newMessage.id)">Comment</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

everything is working. i can send my messages, and i can even send posts, but i get null from ng-model="myComment"

here is the method in js controller

```
 $scope.addComment = function (messageId) {
        myChatHub.server.addComment(messageId, userName, $scope.myComment);
    };
```

can you please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking the golden rule of always having a dot in `ng-model` .. or in other words using an object

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope and your primitive assigned to `ng-model` therefore only exists in the child scope since primitives have no inheritance.

Create  model object in controller

```
$scope.model={}
```

And then use that  `ng-model="model.myComment"` and change your post to:

```
$scope.addComment = function (messageId) {
        myChatHub.server.addComment(messageId, userName, $scope.model.myComment);
};
```

[This 3 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc) will be very enlightening